# why is the node paypal payer_id is not being returned

Tags: node.js, paypal

In my node app the paypal response is not sending me a payer_id param

[ { field: 'payer_id', issue: 'Required field missing' } ]

what am i missing?

thanks

Ian

Answer (score 0):

@iancrowther If you would not mind elaborating more, what stage are you needing the payer_id?

1) If you were trying to accept a payment via paypal, you direct the user to the approval_url on PayPal so that user can approve the payment. After the user approves the payment, PayPal redirects the user back to the return_url you specified, and appends the payer ID in return url as PayerID. The documentation for the requests are at

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/#execute-the-payment

2) If you are storing a credit card in vault for secure storage and charging later, you can include a unique payer_id in the request. The docs are at

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/